# Can I remove these icons from the Windows 10 file explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I never use any of the default Windwos folders and these just get in the way:

[image]

Is there any way that I can remove them from the Windows File Explorer? The icons, I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpin **Quick Access** icons by pressing pin icon on the right of them.

Additionally, you can to *Folder properties > General tab > Privacy section* > uncheck 'Show recently used files in Quick Access' and 'Show frequently used folders in Quick Access'.

To remove '**This PC**' icon from the Navigation pane you need to do registry modifications:
please follow this [guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5352-add-remove-pc-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html).

To remove **Dropbox** icon you again need to do registry modifications (if you don't what to uninstall Dropbox app itself):

- run cmd as administrator
- type the follow 2 commands:

  REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder" /V Attributes /T REG_DWORD /D 4035969101 /F

  REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder" /V Attributes /T REG_DWORD /D 4035969101 /F
- sign-out may be required